# How to use dropdown list to update formview display

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this one out.

I have a dropdownlist (populated from a datasource that concatenates first and last names, and the value is an "employee ID", oh and it's a sql server database).

I also have a formview, that displays all the "employee" information (same database, different sqldatasource. What I'm trying to do is when a user selects an employee from the dropdownlist, it finds the page with the matching employee ID and displays that page.

The formview also needs to keep the paging, to allow a user to select next or previous if needed. (It'd also be nice if the ddl would update on next and previous to show the current viewed employee).

Currently, I have the ddl inside the formview, with a

```
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Employee_ID") %> (which I'm hoping will take care of the ddl showing part, haven't tested that bit as I just woke up,heh).
```

I have autopostback in the ddl set to true, and it is firing the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, I'm just not sure what to do next. (more specifically, I guess I don't know how in C# to find the page with the matching "employee id".

Thanks much for any help!

Comment: I just ended up cheating, and using the selected index to set the pageindex of the formview >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is big example , how to bind and update the form view using drop down select item....

```
    <asp: ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete"
        InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData"
        TypeName="DataSet1TableAdapters.teachersTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
     <DeleteParameters>
       <asp: Parameter Name="Original_PKID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
       <asp: Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
       <asp: Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
       <asp: Parameter Name="department" Type="Int32" />
       <asp: Parameter Name="PKID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
         <asp: Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
         <asp: Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
         <asp: Parameter Name="department" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
  </asp: ObjectDataSource>
    <br />

   <asp: ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete"
    InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData"
    TypeName="DataSet1TableAdapters.departmentsTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp: Parameter Name="Original_PKID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
       <asp: Parameter Name="departmentName" Type="String" />
       <asp: Parameter Name="PKID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
      <InsertParameters>
         <asp: Parameter Name="departmentName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
      </asp:ObjectDataSource></div><br />

      <asp: FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="PKID"
       DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound">
    <EditItemTemplate>
      PKID:
       <asp: Label ID="PKIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PKID") %>'></asp:Label><br />
       name:
        <asp: TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'>
          </asp: TextBox><br />
        lastname:
       <asp: TextBox ID="lastnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'>
    </asp: TextBox><br />
       department:
        <asp: TextBox ID="departmentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("department") %>'>
         </asp:TextBox><br />
       <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
          Text="Update">
      </asp: LinkButton>
         <asp: LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"             CommandName="Cancel"
    Text="Cancel">
         </asp: LinkButton>
     </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
    name:
    <asp: TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'>
    </asp: TextBox><br />
    lastname:
    <asp: TextBox ID="lastnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'>
    </asp: TextBox><br />
    department:
    <asp: TextBox ID="departmentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("department") %>'>
    </asp: TextBox><br />
    <asp: LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
    Text="Insert">
    </asp: LinkButton>
    <asp: LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
    Text="Cancel">
    </asp: LinkButton>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    PKID:
    <asp: Label ID="PKIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PKID") %>'></asp:Label><br />
    name:
    <asp: Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp: Label><br />
    lastname:
    <asp: Label ID="lastnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp: Label><br />
    department:
    <asp: DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2"
    DataTextField="departmentName" DataValueField="PKID">
    </asp: DropDownList><br />
    <asp: LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
    Text="Edit"></asp: LinkButton>
    <asp: LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
    Text="Delete"></asp: LinkButton>
    <asp: LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New"
    Text="New"></asp: LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp: FormView>

In the code behind i used itemdatabound event of the formview so that i set the <strong class="highlight">selected</strong> value for the dropdownlist as follows : 



protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem;
        ((DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue = drv["department"].ToString();
 }
 protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem;
        ((DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedValue = drv["department"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Well that got the ddl showing the right item, but I'm still left clueless when it comes to how to have the form itself show the employee that the user selects from the ddl.
Thanks very much for that bit though, problem is half solved.